# MS Access 2010 - Query for "previous date"

Tags: microsoft-access, database, microsoft-access-2010

I'm working in an access database with the following fields (and others):

Asset; Asset_Date; Start_Date; Start_Time; Office_Stop.

Asset is a # field, Asset_Date is text; Start_Date is Date/Time; Start_Time is Date/Time; and Office_Stop is # (1 or 0).

Asset numbers are unique vehicle identifiers and all of the data are from GPS software. Using the GPS data and ArcGIS, I added the binary "Office_Stop" so I could tell whether each point was an "Office_Stop" or not.

I would like to know where each truck started (Office_Start = 1 or 0).

Logically, the start would be where the truck stopped last.  I know I can export to excel, do a (B2=A1) type formula and move on.  The problem is I have to import new data on a regular basis and I want to avoid multiple excel files and imports/exports in Access - I have too many working files as it is.

Is there a way to have access query the "previous record" for each asset?

Thanks!

Comment: you can use Sub Query (two Select commands) and get TOP 1 record in Descending order. Or create Query & sort date in Descending order for top 1 record.

Comment: Would this be iterative (i.e. every record return the info from the record that happened before it)?

Comment: This can be easily achieved on date like previous date, last week or year.

Comment: Forgive me for asking for clarification, but I'm not sure I follow how to actually do it.  Unfortunately, I'm not very good at writing SQL - I typically use the query builder!  Given the above, can you explain how to write the query?

Comment: This will get previous date using current date, =Date - weekday(date(),2)+1 - iif(weekday(date(),2) = 1, 7,0) AND < Date()